# Common practice to query from django models

Tags: django, django-models

I am planning to build a Django project. I want to make sure that I do things the right way from the beginning. This might be stupid or trivial but I want to know how to do things the right/best way possible.

Lets say I have some models:

```
    class User(Models.model):
        ...

    class Car(Models.model):
        ...
```

And in my code, I want to query from them such as

```
    User.objects.filter(age=25)
    User.objects.filter(gender='male')
    Car.objects.filter(user__age=25)
```

Should I just do the above codes (`User.objects.filter(age=25)`) directly where it's needed or should I have a module to keep all queries organized in one place like

```
    # this is queries.py
    def getUsersByAge(age):
        return User.objects.filter(age=age)

    def getCarByUserAge(age):
        return Car.objects.filter(user__age=age)
    ...
```

And in my other places, I would call `queries.getUserByAge(25)` instead of directly calling `User.objects.filter(age=age)`.

I think having separate functions to do this stuff isn't necessary because Django already provides us with good abstractions. But having a single place where all related queries are stored might be a good code management?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is opinion based, but your use case by having them in separate methods seems very limited to me.

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge it is perfectly fine to make the queries directly at the appropriate places.

I do not see how your proposed abstraction adds any value. The exception would be if you modify the queried data somehow before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the queries in multiple places, it's probably a good idea. In the future if a query changes or needs permissions applied, you can just change the method. But I wouldn't bother creating the methods until you are *actually* writing duplicate queries.